# Is there any alternative to check and then act on synchronized list?

Tags: java, list, collections

```
List synchronizedList=new Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
synchronized (synchronizedList) {
    if (synchronizedList.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(synchronizedList.get(0));
    }
}
```

for the above code first we check and then act.can we achieve this functionality using CopyOnwriteArrayList without check and then act.

Comment: Why do think you need that synchronized check when using a synchronized list? And more importantly, what is the problem you intend to solve?

Comment: Why does it need to be synchronized when all you're doing here is reading?

Comment: There is no `getIfPresent` method in COWAL - so no. Why do you want to change the current code?

Comment: @GhostCat "Why do think you need that synchronized check when using a synchronized list?" Because only individual operations are synchronized. The list's size can change between the call to `size()` and the call to `get(0)`.

Comment: @JoeC If another thread empties the list between the if and the println, the code will throw an exception.

Comment: `new` is not needed in `List synchronizedList=new Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());`

Comment: Andy: true when we talk about parallel REMOVAL of elements. If stuff is only added, then such extra checks are not required. Thus I asked about the real problem at hand.

Comment: Note that there's no point in synchronizing a local variable, anyway, if it's not leaked from the method. But then, this must be a toy example, because the list is always empty otherwise.

Comment: But, with a COWAL, you could use something like `list.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println)`.

Comment: @GhostCat OP didn't say anything about the types of operation that the list undergoes.

Comment: @GhostCat even if there are only additions, the get() should come while the list is resizing its array, and you could very well get null instead of the actual first element. Don't take shortcut. If you're writing and reading from a list concurrently, all accesses must be synchronized.

Comment: So in essence nobody is really sure what the question is exactly about... And not a single comment /update by the questioner...

Comment: Actually i want to use the COWAL in my concurrent programming application.and checked for any getIfPresent like functionality is available in COWAL. in my code snippet i used synchronized wrapper but i want to use the COWAL with same functionality.

Comment: I suspect you want to use one of the concurrent `Queue` implementations, not COWAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. Even the [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) doesn't provide an atomic operation to check if an element exists in the list and execute some code on it like the `Map`'s interface `computeIfPresent`. To make a long story short - you'll have to implement that logic yourself, like you did in the snippet in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is safe to do without synchronization:

```
// given CopyOnWriteArrayList<T> list
Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    return iterator.next();
}
```

Safety is guaranteed by this property of [`CopyOnWriteArrayList.iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#iterator()):

> The returned iterator provides a snapshot of the state of the list when the iterator was constructed. No synchronization is needed while traversing the iterator.

So if the list was not empty at the time you got the iterator,
the first item (or any other, for that matter),
will be still there and accessible,
even if other threads may have called `remove` or `clear` on the list.
(And the reason this works is thanks to the copy-on-write nature of this class.)